# Yii2 Update query in controller not working

Tags: yii2

I’m trying to update 'page' column but it is not working. I want to update only one column by changing the data from 4 to 5. The data type is an integer.

**View**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <?= Html::a('Add as memoriam', ['update-status', 'id' => $model->ID], [
            'class' => 'btn bg-maroon',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to add '.$model->name.' into the dearly departed?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionUpdateStatus($id)
{

    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $model->page = 5; 
    if ($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));

    return $this->redirect(['my-obituary']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Using [save()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#save()-detail)**

This method will call [insert()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecordinterface#insert()-detail) when [$isNewRecord](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#$isNewRecord-detail) is true, or [update()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#update()-detail) when [$isNewRecord](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#$isNewRecord-detail) is false.

```
public function actionUpdateStatus($id)
{
     $model = $this->findModel($id);
     $model->page = 5; 

     if ($model->save(true, ['page'])) {
          $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
     }

     return $this->redirect(['my-obituary']);
}
```

**2. Using [updateAttributes()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#updateAttributes()-detail)**

This method is a shortcut to [update()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#update()-detail) when data validation is not needed and only a small set attributes need to be updated. You may specify the attributes to be updated as name list or name-value pairs. If the latter, the corresponding attribute values will be modified accordingly. The method will then save the specified attributes into database.

Note that this method will not perform data validation and will not trigger events.

```
public function actionUpdateStatus($id)
{
     $model = $this->findModel($id);
     $model->page = 5; 

     if ($model->updateAttributes(['page' => 5])) {
          $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
     }

     return $this->redirect(['my-obituary']);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works by using both of your solution. Thank you !